# How do I reference a model object in the example section of documentation in an R package

Tags: r, r-package

I'm creating an R package. In my package project folder, I have a model object saved as a `.rds` file. in a folder called `data`. Additionally, I have a function saved in the `R` folder.

How do I reference the model object in the example section of documentation of the function in the `R` folder?

I also have the same questions for dataset files saved as `.rds` files in the `data` folder. How do I reference those datasets in the example section when documenting functions.

Comment: https://r-pkgs.org/data.html#sec-documenting-data

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need you could find out in the R packages book which is distributed for free. [Hadley Wickham and Jenny Bryan](https://r-pkgs.org/data.html)

[This part of the book is directly connected with your question but please check others too](https://r-pkgs.org/data.html#sec-documenting-data)

I recommend usage of `usethis` package, which togather with `roxygen2` does most things you need.